# Finding the correct SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have those tables:

```
- LEARNERS: LEARNER_ID, LEARNER_NAME
- PACKAGE: PACKAGE_ID, PACKAGE_NAME
- LEARNER_PACKAGES: LEARNER_ID (From LEARNERS table), 
  PACKAGE_ID (From PACKAGE table), DUE_DATE, DATE_COMPLETED (NULLABLE)
```

I'd like to create a SQL query to return all the packages for each learner:

For LEARNER_ID 123, return all his packages:

```
LEARNER_NAME, PACKAGE_NAME, DUE_DATE, DATE_COMPLETED
```

I've tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.PACKAGE_NAME, lp.PACKAGE_ID, lp.DUE_DATE, lp.DATE_COMPLETED 
FROM LEARNER_PACKAGES lp,
     PACKAGE p
WHERE lp.LEARNER_ID = 123 AND
      lp.PACKAGE_ID = p.ID;
```

It returns some unexpected result, only part of the desired output.
But I have no clue what to try next.

Oracle express 12.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve]

Comment: @jarlh I believe you have everything you need? Do you need me to add values?

Comment: Please explain the results you are getting and why they are not correct.

Comment: Sample data and expected result should always be provided when asking this type of questions.

Comment: @jarlh Will do next time.

Comment: That will be excellent!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to run it on another machine, and it seems to work correctly.

However, I am taking your tip and I'll use `JOIN`.

```
SELECT p.PACKAGE_NAME, lp.PACKAGE_ID, lp.DUE_DATE, lp.DATE_COMPLETED 
FROM LEARNER_PACKAGES lp JOIN
     PACKAGE p
     ON lp.PACKAGE_ID = p.ID
WHERE lp.LEARNER_ID = 123 ;
```

Thanks to and @Jobin and @Gordon Linoff for the query.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the only thing you need from the package table is the package name. Have you tried getting the data without joining the package table over? This would help determine if the join is the issue or something else.

I would also eliminate the second line of you where statement as that would be stated in the join, if you are going to test removing the join.

I would also use explicit join syntax and test joining on packageID or name to see how your results respond.

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks correct, but it is better written with `JOIN`:

```
SELECT p.PACKAGE_NAME, lp.PACKAGE_ID, lp.DUE_DATE, lp.DATE_COMPLETED 
FROM LEARNER_PACKAGES lp JOIN
     PACKAGE p
     ON lp.PACKAGE_ID = p.ID
WHERE lp.LEARNER_ID = 123 ;
```

Can you explain the issues you are having with this query?

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT p.PACKAGE_NAME, lp.PACKAGE_ID, lp.DUE_DATE, lp.DATE_COMPLETED 
FROM PACKAGE p, LEARNER_PACKAGES lp
WHERE lp.PACKAGE_ID = p.PACKAGE_ID
AND lp.LEARNER_ID = 123 ;